# Remove all parent node's content if any child node has no value

Tags: c#, xml, nodes, parent-child

I want to remove the parent node if any of its children have no value.
I've tried several methods and nothing works.  Remove "S_Industry_Code" parent and all its child nodes if child node "E_Code_List_Qualifier" or "E_Industry_Code is blank.  I want a generic case so the code can be used in other empty parent or child nodes too.  Please help! Any suggestions?

```
namespace TEST
{
    class Remove_Empty_Tags
    {    
        public static void Main()
        {    
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();               
            doc.Load(@"C:\Users\TestDLMS\out\I_636806391809983753.xml");    
            new RemoveNulls().RemoveEmptyNodes(doc);    
            doc.Save(@"C:\users\Desktop\AllNullsRemoved.xml");    
        }    
    }
}   

   class RemoveNulls
   {
        public void RemoveEmptyNodes(XmlDocument doc)
        {
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//node()");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                if ((node.Attributes != null && node.Attributes.Count == 0) && (node.ChildNodes != null && node.ChildNodes.Count == 0))
                {
                  //  node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node); //removes only nodes that are blank
                      node.ParentNode.RemoveAll(); //removes child nodes leaves empty parent 
                  //  node.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveAll(); //removes everything
                }
       }
   }
// Content of XML file
<File>
  <T_Requisition_511R Standard="X12">
    <S_Transaction_Set_Header>
      <E_Transaction_Set_Code>511</E_Transaction_Set_Code>       
      <E_Transaction_Set_Number>0001</E_Transaction_Set_Number>
    </S_Transaction_Set_Header>
    <S_Beginning_Segment_for_Material_Management>
      <E_Transaction_Set_Purpose_Code>00</E_Transaction_Set_Purpose_Code>
      <E_Transaction_Type_Code>A0</E_Transaction_Type_Code>
      <E_Date>20181217</E_Date>
      <E_Time>152620</E_Time>
    </S_Beginning_Segment_for_Material_Management>
    <L_Assigned_Number>
      <L_Code_Source_Information>
        <S_Industry_Code>
          <E_Code_List_Qualifier_Code>A9</E_Code_List_Qualifier_Code>
          <E_Industry_Code>    </E_Industry_Code>
        </S_Industry_Code>
        <S_Industry_Code>
          <E_Code_List_Qualifier_Code>79</E_Code_List_Qualifier_Code>
          <E_Industry_Code>03</E_Industry_Code>
        </S_Industry_Code>
        <S_Industry_Code>
          <E_Code_List_Qualifier_Code>80</E_Code_List_Qualifier_Code>
          <E_Industry_Code>   </E_Industry_Code>
        </S_Industry_Code>
      </L_Code_Source_Information>
    </L_Assigned_Number>
  </T_Requisition_511R>
</File>
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to be properly indented. The namespace and the (probable) class definitions may be out-of-sync. Please correct that with an edit to the question.

Comment: Your xml is not valid, its missing a </S_Industry_Code>

Comment: Added the missing </S_Industry_Code> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string xml_string = @"<File>...</File>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(xml_string);
var empty = xml.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Elements().Count() == 0 && d.Value.Trim() == "")
            .Select(d => d.Parent);
empty.Remove();
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Johny.  It WORKED. I've been racking my brain for weeks trying to resolve this issue. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for the case when the attributes are null.

This is easier IMO using XDocument vs XmlDocument. Here is an example:

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\file.xml");

    doc =  RemoveNulls.RemoveEmptyNodes(doc);
    doc.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class RemoveNulls
{
    public static XDocument RemoveEmptyNodes(XDocument doc)
    {
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants().ToList()){

            if(!element.HasAttributes && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Value) && !element.HasElements)
                element.Remove();
        }
        return doc;     
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code does not work.  It removed all the values from the parent-child nodes. I want to remove parent-child tags and inner content where child tags has no value.  Any other suggestions??

Comment: Thanks your input.  I had to change doc.dump to doc.Save(@"C://desktop/tst.xml") because dump was not recognized in my Visual Studio version.  Changed element.Remove() to element.Parent.RemoveAll() because it only removes the blank child node tag.  Any other suggestions?